# How can i create php forms which can i fill from command line (cmd)?

Tags: php, html, curl, cmd

I have tried curl on html from but show error

```
curl -d user="Kirk" http://xxxxxxx.site/form.php
```

but in return

```
<html>

<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>

<body>

<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>

<hr><center>nginx</center>

</body></html>
```

I've also tried adding a user-agent, but I'm getting the same error.

i want to store value inside the "user"(html form element) to text file(stored on webserver) using command line. i am able to create this using web-based interface but i want it using command line.

my code for web-based interface
html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Store form data in .txt file</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="data.php" method="post">
    Enter Your Text Here:<br>
    <input type="text" name="textdata"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
    
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

php:

```
<?php
              
if(isset($_POST['textdata']))
{
$data=$_POST['textdata'];
$fp = fopen('log.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: i want to make a form which can be filled from command line interface.